# Do Caitlyn's Traps still reveal stealthed targets?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you step on one of Caitlyn's traps (or any other champion skill that reveals for a duration) will it still reveal champions once they enter stealth?

So, if I stepped on a trap, and I entered stealth as Kha'Zix, Teemo, etc, would I still be revealed to her and her teammates?  Or would I still enter stealth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

If you notice an eye will be set in top of the enemy as he steps the trap. This effect lasts 9 seconds.

From the [wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Caitlyn):

"The trap also grants true sight of the target for 9 seconds."

Comment: I am aware of the eye, I was just wondering if that still reveals a stealth character if they go into stealth after they are revealed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. The idea is that any skill that reveals a champion will not reveal a stealthed champion. However, if a champion becomes un-stealthed while that de-buff is still active, they will be revealed, and true sight given even if they were to re-stealth, for as long as the de-buff applies. A champion that would be stealthed if not for the de-buff, will appear as translucent. The only difference between Caitlyn's Yordle Snaptraps `W` and Nidalee's Bushwhack `W`, as compared to other revealing skills, is that the traps also initially break the enemy's stealth. For example, if a Jinx hits a visible Teemo with her "Zap!" `W` then the Teemo tries to stealth to hide, even if Teemo stands still, and does not perform any actions, he will still be revealed. On the other hand, if Teemo was invisible when the "Zap!" struck, he will remain invisible unless he chooses to break stealth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the trap does reveal Invisibility and gives you a debuff that causes two eyes to appear on top of your champion.

Every trap that causes this vision debuff (Caitlyn/Nidalee) will reveal your champion, however you will enter stealth but you will still be visible to the enemy team for the debuffs duration.

The only "Eye-Debuffs" I know that don't reveal stealth are: Corki Q, Clairvoyance, Blue trinket.

Also not every trap will cause you to be visible to the enemy team. If a Kha'Zix walks into a teemo trap he will still be able to go and/or stay invisible during his ult.

Comment: I don't think Kog'Maw's 'Eye-Debuff' reveals stealth either.